# Disable LAN connection at startup in Debian

Tags: debian, startup, network-interface, lan, wicd

How to disable LAN connection at startup in Debian Jessie? Ido not know what establishes that connection. Is it any configuration file or my wicd that starts on boot. But when I open wicd I can see that connection via the wire is established after system startup. I do not want this connection because the modem connection does not work then.
How to disable LAN on boot?

interfaces file:

```
root@debian:cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

Comment: What is in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: I put it into the question

Comment: Your network isn't being brought up automatically during boot, so it would be WICD or NetworkManager or whatever your DE is using to do the connectiviity.

Comment: Actually you can disable networking from NetworkManager. Or you can leave LAN connection unconfigure.I also used modem connection.I didnt configure my LAN connection.

Comment: You can delete lan connection from wicd.You can add it again when you needed lan connection.

Comment: @supriady I have been looking for the switch in wicd gui or the option in wicd conf files to disable auto lan connection but have not succeed. I have two usb modems for internet and they stop working when the lan is connected. I do not know why. But roaima solution worked. Another solution was to unplug the lan cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines define the actions to be applied to the `eth0` interface:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The man page for interfaces (`man interfaces`) will describe it in glorious detail, but essentially, it's saying

- If we have an `eth0` interface, allow it to be defined
- When we find `eth0` bring it up with DHCP

In older versions of Debian you could simply comment out both lines. However, in newer versions this tells other network managers to take control of the interface, so that's not advisable.

Instead, change `dhcp` to `manual`, which tells the other network managers that you want control of the interface retained in this file, but that you don't want it brought up automatically:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```